# Custom metrics not being sent to datadog

Tags: datadog

I am running the datadog agent using docker

```
    DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 \
    docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
          -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
          -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
          -e DD_API_KEY=<my_api_key> \
          -e DD_DOGSTATD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true \
          -e DD_LOG_LEVEL=debug \
          -p 127.0.0.1:8125:8125/udp \
          datadog/agent:latest
```

I want to send custom metrics using dogstatsd. When I run

```
    echo -n "custom_metric:60|g|#shell" | nc -4u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125
```

I can see in wireshark that the udp packet was successful from the source to the destination but this metric is not being submitted to datadog. Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a typo in your command. `DD_DOGSTATD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC`  is used instead of `DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC`

I usually used the below command for testing with Datadog:

```
DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 docker run -d \
    --name dd-agent \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -e DD_API_KEY=<api-key> \
    -e DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC="true" \
    -p 8125:8125/udp \
    -p 8126:8126/tcp \
    datadog/agent:latest
```